# Openconnect works via CLI; how can I get it to work in NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, networkmanager, vpn, openconnect

Openconnect works fine via the command line.

```
$ sudo openconnect foo.com/bar
POST https://foo.com/bar
Attempting to connect to server 1.2.3.4:443
Connected to 1.2.3.4:443
SSL negotiation with foo.com
Connected to HTTPS on foo.com
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Fri, 04 Aug 2017 08:28:32 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Aggregate-Auth: 1
HTTP body chunked (-2)
XML POST enabled
Please enter your username and password.
Username:baz
Password:
```

However, it fails via network manager. I click to connect to the VPN, which brings up a window. I then click the "connect" icon again, and I'm presented with `Failed to find or parse web form in login page`. The log is as follows.

```
GET https://foo.com/bar
Attempting to connect to server 1.2.3.4:443
Connected to 1.2.3.4:443
SSL negotiation with foo.com
Connected to HTTPS on foo.com
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 110
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Close
Date: Fri, 04 Aug 2017 08:31:22 GMT
HTTP body length:  (110)
Failed to find or parse web form in login page
```

There are a few differences, e.g. `GET` vs. `POST`, and `Content-Type`. I'm not sure if this is important. Here is the NetworkManager config file:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/foo_VPN
[connection]
id=foo_VPN
uuid=<random string>
type=vpn
permissions=user:sparhawk:;

[vpn]
autoconnect-flags=0
certsigs-flags=0
cookie-flags=2
enable_csd_trojan=no
gateway=foo.cam/bar
gateway-flags=2
gwcert-flags=2
lasthost-flags=0
pem_passphrase_fsid=no
protocol=nc
xmlconfig-flags=0
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openconnect

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

I'm using an up-to-date Arch Linux, with `openconnect` and `networkmanager-openconnect` installed. I'm using KDE Plasma, if relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but now it's working. Perhaps an update fixed this.